# CSS display but keep row height

Tags: css

I am using a table to display some data and for one row, I am displaying a 35-character preview of a (possibly) longer string.  When the user does a mouse-over on one of the previews, it displays the full text next to it.

The problem is when the full text is displayed, the `tr` height is changed to fit the full text, but I want it to stay the same size.

```
<td><a href="link.asp?tid=<%=ID%>" onmouseover="showDetails(<%=ID%>);"><%=shortPreview%></a>
<br/><div class="details" style="display:none;" id="<%=ID%>"><%=rsTickets("details")%></div></td>
```

CSS

```
.details {
  position:relative;
  top:-15px;
  left:260px;
  background-color:#FFFFAA;
  z-index:1;
  padding-top:5px;
  padding-bottom:5px;
  padding-right:15px;
  padding-left:5px;
  border:1px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:#CCCC99;

  -moz-border-radius: 1em 2em 2em 1em;
  border-radius: 1em 2em 2em 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a fixed size div inside your cell and set it to `position: relative`. Inside that div put your details one and set it to `position: absolute;`. This should work for 99%.

Comment: Set a fixed height to your cell (td) and add the overflow to it. Maybe that will help.

Comment: Row style: `style="height:10px;overflow:hidden;"`

Comment: Nope.  No longer displays popup at all.

Comment: Ok, another approach. Put a fixed size div inside your cell and set it to `position: relative`. Inside that div put your details one and set it to `position: absolute;`. This should work for 99%

Comment: Sort of `<td><div class="container">COntent.... <div class="details">...</div></div></td>`

Comment: Worked, though I can keep the inner div to relative, since it seems to still work. Thanks.

Comment: It definitely should work on IE. I would suggest tweaking position. I'll get a demo running over lunch to verify.

Comment: Actually, you were right, it works in IE if the inner div is set to `position: absolute` (I didn't realize absolutes inside relatives are based on the relative position)

Comment: That's the only way to use absolutes - inside relatives. Otherwise you lose their practicality completely. Glad it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Thing is that when you set an object to be relative, then it is relative to the objects around it. This means that if you change the height of the div (or in this case, shows it), the surrounding objects will adapt to this change. So when you set the div to be visible the td, which encapsulates it, will change it's height as well.

Setting the div to an absolute position solves the problem, but then it might get difficult to position it right. Unless you put it in another div. If you put an absolute div within a relative div, then the absolute div will be absolute to the relavite div, thus solving the problem. Here's an example:

```
<table>
    <tr><td><div style=position:relative>
          This div will not affect the td more than will this text.
          <div style=position:absolute;top10px;>
               This div will not affect the td, since it's absolute, and will be
               10px from the top of the outer div
          </div>
    </div></td></tr>
</table>
```

This should do the trick. Works for me at least.

Comment: If you go this route then you might as well put the content outside the table all together.  Also, I am needing this to be a variable length option for several rows of the table, which I would prefer to not have the full text display at the same spot on the screen for each option, though I suppose a counter would help solve that issue.